# Sending emails to all subscribed users in an Orchard CMS workflow

Tags: orchardcms

Everytime new content is created I wish to send an email to all users that have a "receive updates" property field set.

"Receive updates" is a field added to the User content type and I have a workflow triggered by new content being created.

I'm wondering if there exists some kind of generic "iteration" activity for the workflows feature  that can iterate over a projection and trigger once for each result of the projection? I figure this would allow me to then trigger an email for each user that has the "receive updates" field set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't an existing interation workflow activity. To acheive this you're going to have to go deeper into Orchard and write your own module.

If you'd like to send emails to all your users I would copy the Email Activity Module and use this as the basis for a new Email All Users activity. This will do what you want, be sueful to others if you choose to share, and be easier than writing a more generic iteration activity.

Comment: Thanks Richard, this is what I suspected. I'm thinking of implementing a "Query Trigger" activity that can be configured with a query and a signal, and will trigger the signal once for each content item returned by the query, including the content item in the target context. In a way it would be like the existing "Trigger" activity, except it will trigger the configured signal multiple times, once for each content item in the query.